# Is it possible to use a single query to achieve related purchase history?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table consists of all order history like this:

```
table: orderhistory

OrderID       ProductID       CustomerID        Quantity        
     1                   4                       1                        1
     1                   5                       1                        2
     1                   6                       1                        1
     2                   4                       2                        1
     2                   3                       2                        1
     2                   5                       2                        1
```

OrderID and ProductID are primary keys.
So purchase history related to product 4 consists of product 3, 5 and 6. And product 5 should be prior to other records as it appears twice together with 4 in a single order. How can I use a single query to grab that information?

Desired result: (query for related history of product 4)

```
ProductID       Freq       
     5                   2
     6                   1
     3                   1
```

Comment: Please provide "purchase history" table's schema

Comment: @Naren it's shown as the example above with data

Comment: Can you show an example of the expected result?

Comment: Please check the query given in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query will fetch the necessary data.

```
SELECT 

      DISTINCT PRODUCTID

 FROM 

      [ORDERHISTORY] oh

 WHERE

      oh.OrderID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM ORDERHISTORY WHERE PRODUCTID = 4 )
```

Comment: WHERE oh.OrderID IN (...) **AND ProductID <> 4**. Also, you need to produce counts somehow. Use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT.

Comment: @NSF: I forgot that you need it in order.
Use GROUP BY as suggested by Andriy and Add a ORDER  BY at the end.

Then you will get the data as required.

Comment: That works but...it has two problems: 1. it will return the queried product (4 in this example) . This is easy to solve as Andriy said. 2. it won't return the frequency, which means it's not guaranteed that 5 is prior than 3. And that's actually the crux of the problem.

Comment: @NSF: I forgot that you need it in order. Use GROUP BY as suggested by Andriy and Add a ORDER BY at the end. Then you will get the data as required.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ProductID, count(ProductID) as Freq from orderhistory group by ProductID;
```

you can place where as per your need like..

```
select ProductID, count(ProductID) as Freq from orderhistory 
where ProductID in (5,6,3) group by ProductID;
```

OR

```
select ProductID, count(ProductID) as Freq from orderhistory 
where ProductID != 4 group by ProductID;
```

Comment: Just to confirm....
@manurajhada: The second query is right, but how will we get to know the where clause value "(5,6,3)" while writing the query, I mean we dont know whats there in the database. We know that we data w.r.t 4 but how can we know about 3,5 and 6 before the execution of script.

Comment: See @Naren: the main logic is about selection, as i said `you can place where as per your need`.

Comment: Nice to know something new, "absolute selection". Thanks.